# How to make a web directory with Desciption Field?

Tags: apache, directory

I want to know how to you make web directory like this

http://www.ibiblio.org/pub/docs/

It has a description field for each file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [mod_autoindex](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_autoindex.html) and the [AddDescription](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_autoindex.html#adddescription) directive.